# Настройка Google Analytics и GTM для конверсии

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я делаю.
На сайте подключен GTM и google analytics.
В GTM создан тэг(Track type="Event", Category="MarketoSubmit18", Action = "MarketoSubmit18") для отслеживания маркето формы.
Теперь чтобы отследить конверсию мне нужно еще в Google Analytics в Admin->Goals создать новую цель с типом 'Событие' с категорией 'MarketoSubmit18'?

В моем понимании GTM нужен для управления тегов. А вот как созданный тэг применить в Google Analytics и увидеть конверсию?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы смотреть в отчете Conversion >> Goals цель нужно создать. Но вы так же можете просматривать данные как событие в Behaviour >> Events.